# Unable to run Jasmine using maven

Tags: maven, unit-testing, jasmine, phantomjs

I configured my pom.xml to run unit tests using Jasmine and phantomJS.

below the is pom.xml part

```
<profile>
<id>jasmine</id>
<activation>
    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
</activation>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>install</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <version>1.9.7</version>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.searls</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasmine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <debug>pl</debug>
                <skipJasmineTests>false</skipJasmineTests>
                <webDriverClassName>org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver</webDriverClassName>
                <webDriverCapabilities>
                    <capability>
                        <name>phantomjs.binary.path</name>
                        <value>${phantomjs.binary}</value>
                    </capability>
                </webDriverCapabilities>
                <jsSrcDir>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/app</jsSrcDir>
                <jsTestSrcDir>${basedir}/src/test</jsTestSrcDir>
                <sourceIncludes>
                    <include>**/app.js</include>
                    <include>*.js</include>
                </sourceIncludes>
                <preloadSources>
                    <source>${bower-components}/angular/angular.min.js</source>
                    <source>${bower-components}/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js</source>
                </preloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Onc e I run  "mvn -Pjasmine clean install"  I'm getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.searls:jasmine-maven-plugin:2.2:test (default) on project widget-app-web: The jasmine-maven-plugin encountered an exception:
[ERROR] org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
[ERROR] Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
[ERROR] System info: host: 'h-MacBook-Pro-sl-myr.local', ip: '192.168.0.21', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
[ERROR] Driver info: driver.version: PhantomJSDriver
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:115)
[ERROR] at org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver.<init>(PhantomJSDriver.java:104)
```

Can't find any solution for this.
Any suggestions how to solve this ?